# Oracle query for ATAN - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I have code as follows:

```
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;               
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT SUM(ATAN((CASE WHEN (t0.CustomerID = 'Test') THEN 1 ELSE 1 END))) value FROM Customers  t0 WHERE(t0.CustomerID = 'Test')";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                              
while (reader.Read())
{
    decimal value = reader.GetDecimal(0);
}
```

The error I got - "Specified cast is not valid"

Could someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.
Joon

Comment: Give us sample data to work on

Comment: I got case error on this: decimal value = reader.GetDecimal(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem resolved as follows:

```
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;               
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT SUM(ATAN((CASE WHEN (t0.CustomerID = 'Test') THEN 1 ELSE 1 END))) value FROM Customers  t0 WHERE(t0.CustomerID = 'Test')";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                              
while (reader.Read())
{
  decimal value = reader.GetOracleDecimal(0);
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Does your query return a row ?  Just wondering if this is caused by the potential of a null being returned.

```
SQL> with customers as
  2   ( select 'Test' CustomerID from dual )
  3  SELECT SUM(ATAN((CASE WHEN (t0.CustomerID = 'Test') THEN 1 ELSE 1 END))) value FROM Customers  t0 WHERE(t0.CustomerID = 'Test');

     VALUE
----------
.785398163

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> with customers as
  2   ( select 'Test1' CustomerID from dual )
  3  SELECT SUM(ATAN((CASE WHEN (t0.CustomerID = 'Test') THEN 1 ELSE 1 END))) value FROM Customers  t0 WHERE(t0.CustomerID = 'Test');

     VALUE
----------
     (null)
```

Perhaps the latter case above is the cause ?

Comment: The former is the case, which has value .785398163 I want to cast in c#. Thanks